# When does a $\sigma(X)$-measurable function $Y$ filter through $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\sigma(X)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a function $X: \Omega \to (E, \mathcal E)$ and suppose that $Y: (\Omega, \sigma(X)) \to (F, \mathcal F)$ is a function to another measurable space and measurable w.r.t. the generated $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)$.

When does $Y$ factor through $X$, i.e. when does there exist a function $Z: E \to F$ such that $Y = Z \circ X$? When is $Z$ measurable?

I know that such $Z$ always exists for discrete random variables $X$ (i.e. $E = $ countable set, $\mathcal E = \mathcal P(E)$) as then $\sigma(X) = \{\bigcup_{x \in S} \{X = x\} \mid S \subset E\}$ and $Y$ is constant on each set $\{X = x\}$. But what about other measurable spaces $(E, \mathcal E)$, in particular $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ and Polish spaces?

Thank you.

Comment: This $Z$ exists always. This is known as [Doob-Dynkin lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma).

Comment: Thank you, I had never heard of the lemma before.

Comment: Many people haven't. It is my trump in my sleeve. :)